# Python, Regex to replace strings contains “/”, “(” and “)”

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to write a regex to replace matched string question.

A is the short string and B is a long one contains A.

```
A = "5456-module - PAN-12"
B = "5456-module - PAN-12 (100%); 2883-controller - CHG-24; 2898-battery - BAT-12-100 (12 V/100); 2917-panel - MKT-200 (4 x PAN-12-50)"
```

I want to remove A part in B, as long as it contains A with “ (100%)”.

This line works well.

```
Print re.sub(A + r'\s[()]100%[()];\s', "", B)
```

And it returns:

```
2883-controller - CHG-24; 2898-battery - BAT-12-100 (12 V/100); 2917-panel - MKT-200 (4 x PAN-12-50)
```

However, when the A string contains “/” and “(”, “)”. It doesn’t work. Like:

```
new_A = "5456-module - PAN-12 V/50 Wp (1/2 Inch)"
new_B = "5456-module - PAN-12 V/50 Wp (1/2 Inch) (100%); 2883-controller - CHG-24; 2898-battery - BAT-12-100 (12 V/100); 2917-panel - MKT-200 (4 x PAN-12-50)"
```

When I run the same line:

```
Print re.sub(new_A + r'\s[()]100%[()];\s', "", new_B).
```

nothing happens.

How can I make the line work?

Comment: Try wrapping `re.escape(....)` around your existing expression and passing that. Your search string contains characters that regex interprets as meta-characters, so you'd have to escape them to get it working.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thank you. do you mean re.sub(new_A + re.escape(r'\s[()]100%[()];\s'), "", new_B)?

Comment: I mean `re.escape(A) + r'\s[()]100%[()];\s'`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, genius! could you please answer this question so that I can choose yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` in your second example contains parentheses which the regex engine interprets as metacharacters (capture groups in this case). Since you want them matched literally, you'd need to *escape* them. This would involve appending a backslash before each such character.

`re`, however, provides a nice little convenience function, [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), that does this for you.

Here's what you'd need to pass as your modified regex:

```
r'{}\s\(100%\);\s'.format(re.escape(A))
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED, marvelous! thank you again, sir, for making the world more beautiful!

Comment: @MarkK You are welcome. Also, I fixed your expression a bit. ;-) You didn't need `[()]`, just the appropriate escaped paren.